# Swift 'WKInterfaceLabel' does not have a member named 'text'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xcode6.1

I'm working on an iWatch application and I'm getting the following error:

> 'WKInterfaceLabel' does not have a member named 'text'

The outlet:

```
@IBOutlet var numField: WKInterfaceLabel!
```

Relevant code block which causes the error:

```
func updateDisplay() {
    // If the value is an integer, don't show a decimal point
    var iAcc = Int(accumulator)
    if accumulator - Double(iAcc) == 0 {
        numField.text = "\(iAcc)"
    } else {
        numField.text = "\(accumulator)"
    }
```

Specifically:

```
numField.text = "\(iAcc)"
```

and

```
numField.text = "\(accumulator)"
```

I've tried [optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) as suggested in [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964901/6-0-1-and-table-changes-uilabel-does-not-have-a-member-named-text), but I am still having issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [the class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/index.html)

There is no property for text. The way to set the text is to call the setText method:

```
numField.setText("\(Acc)")
```

or

```
numField.setText("\(accumulator"))
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you. I had used setText as a solution, but my usage was incorrect.

Comment: set text is to set text on WKInterfaceLabel but how to get the text on WKInterfaceLabel for string comparison.

Comment: @PradumnaPatil this is not possible on WKInterfaceLabel even on watchOS 2

Answer (score 0):

There is not `text` property for label. You've to use `setText` property.

```
func updateDisplay() {
    // If the value is an integer, don't show a decimal point
    var iAcc = Int(accumulator)

    if accumulator - Double(iAcc) == 0 {
        numField.setText("\(iAcc)")
    } else {
        numField.setText("\(accumulator)")
    }
}
```

Below is WKInterfaceLabel class declaration:

[image: Screenshot]